# Problem with Ubuntu and loading

Tags: 11.10, 12.04

What is going wrong when, I have to use Ubuntu 2D because, when I try logging into Ubuntu, it loads slow and wont show and side bars or load anything, so if someone could help me, please would be appreciated. Tried so many things, I even upgraded my OS but it followed and I still can't access Ubuntu to play my minecraft game, so if anyone has any help, much appreciated.

Comment: Is the problem that you currently can only use Unity 2D and you want to use something else, or is the problem that you are currently using something else but want to use Unity 2D?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Ubuntu are you using 11.10 or 12.04 (both are tagged)? Is this a new install or an upgrade? If so, you may want to try installing proprietary drivers for your graphics card...go to the wrench icon in upper right hand corner of your screen and click "system settings" then "additional drivers" Ubuntu will then search for specific drivers for your graphics card. Do you have enough RAM? I had 512 in my netbook and had to by a 1gig stick to get Unity to work well in 3d.

If this doesn't work we will probably need more info to help you. How much RAM do you have? What graphics card are you using? What specifically have you tried? Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: opps this should've been a comment, sorry community.